Trying to run Nginx and PHP in kubernates, Originally created them as docker images and they work on docker but php fails in kubernates
Can't get my PHP deployment working, nginx works, and the same php image works fine on docker. I'm brand new to kubernates and pretty new to docker aswell so im not sure what i've done wrong, i'm using minikube on ubuntu
I created these kubernetes files using kompose
php-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: php
  name: php
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: php
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: php
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: php
          name: docker-php
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /srv/working/
              name: php-claim0
            - mountPath: /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
              name: php-claim1
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: php-claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: php-claim0
        - name: php-claim1
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: php-claim1
status: {}


php-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: php-claim0
  name: php-claim0
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}


php-claim1-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: php-claim1
  name: php-claim1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}


I dont seem to be getting any php error messages apart from 'Back-off restarting failed container docker-php in pod php-' in kubernates dashboard
Also how is it getting the contents of the volume, docker got it from the folder in my directory when i was building, is it contained in the image, I dont think it is copying the files that want over, with the nginx its not copying what i specified in the original Dockerfile
Nginx Dockerfile
FROM nginx:alpine
ADD nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
ADD nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/


It's pretty hard in Kubernetes to directly access the contents of persistent volumes.  In normal usage I'd expect your code to be included in the image, not injected via a bind mount or some other kind of external storage.  It looks like this was generated via Kompose; was does the original  Compose file look like?  (There doesn't seem to be a Dockerfile COPY directive that would include your code.)
